# Disable the highlighting of newly installed programs on Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1

On Windows 7, disabling newly installed programs from being highlighted as 'new' in the start menu was a fairly trivial affair, not so it seems on Windows 8.1.

The best solution I could find involves [messing around the registry](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-disable-highlighting-newly-installed-apps-in-windows-8-1-apps-screen/), which doesn't bother me personally on a technical level, but this used to be a single checkbox in Windows 7.

Is there an option in 8.1 I am missing?

Comment: Other than as a GPO (only available in Windows 8.1 Pro or Enterprise), it looks like the registry or a third party program is the only solution.

Comment: Luckily I'm using Enterprise! Still a bit annoying though, what was wrong with a tickbox? Will checkout the GPO option, thanks